# How to print from the web to a local thermal printer connected by usb?

Tags: php, printing, thermal-printer

First of all, sorry for my English, I have been with this problem for quite a few days. I will comment on my situation: I am doing an online ordering system, where once an order is created the ticket printing is triggered. I have tried using Google Cloud Print, it prints but it takes a long time and it does not work as it should, I tried a library called mike42, it prints perfect but not from a website.
The system is in a hosting and I am using PHP together with slim 3, if any of you know how to solve this I would really appreciate it.

The result I want (to be more specific) is the following: The employed user logs on the web (system hosted in the hosting), goes to the orders menu, when he clicks on create the order, this function is executed and prints the ticket directly on the thermal printer connected to the local machine. The same works only if the web is on the local server, which is not what I want.

The title is clear and complete. Printing must take place in client side  browser. Client may be connected to a cloud based accounting or purchase system and POS termal printer is connected through a USB port. Computer mat be a zero client with just a browser.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Are you saying that there are three computers involved: (1) The computer running the browser from which the order is placed, (2) The computer running the website which is hosted using traditional web hosting, (3) The computer to which the printer is attached which is on the network belonging to the company the website belongs to.

Comment: @Juan after your edit, I imagine that the second possible solution that I pointed out may be the most suitable for the case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your answers, I will try the 2 option as you recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, PHP is a server side language, that means it has no communication with the hardware of the local machine.

I've already had to do similar work, and there are two possible solutions:

1- Install PHP on a machine connected to the printer directly, and then print, which is a little impracticable since the server would have to be physically on site.

2 - Generate an output in text formatted for the width of the print and use the window.print () javascript function to call up the print screen, and the user would just click on print.

When I needed it I ended up opting for the second alternative, and it worked well, it is a bit boring to get the print size right, but it worked well.

Comment: "that means it has no communication with the hardware of the local machine" — Given that the goal is to print a ticket for an order placed online, that is a *good* thing. It wouldn't do the company much good if the ticket they want to stick on the package they are sending comes out of the printer attached to the customer's computer!

Comment: Certainly, in my case the label should come out on the system user's printer, which, by the way, was a fast food system.
However, if I understand correctly, it needs printing to be done by the system user, but regardless of whether it is the customer using the system or an administrator who should have access to printing, direct sending to the printer is only possible if it is connected directly to the server where PHP is running.